# How to use ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc with Azure Service bus

Tags: c#, azure, message-queue, servicebus

I am trying to delay processing the message, but it doesn't work. It processes the message right away without any delay. This is how I implemented it:

```cs
public QueueClient Client { get; private set; } // set up client correctly

public Task Run()
{
    var messageHandlerOptions = new MessageHandlerOptions(ExceptionReceivedHandler);
    Client.RegisterMessageHandler(ProcessMessageAsync, messageHandlerOptions);
}

private async Task ProcessMessageAsync(Message receivedMessage, CancellationToken token)
{
   try
   {
      throw new Exception("test");
   }
   catch
   {
   if (receivedMessage.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount > 2)
   {
      receivedMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
      Client.AbandonAsync(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
   else
   {
      await Client.AbandonAsync(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken).ConfigureAwait(false);        
   }
}
}
```

The NuGet version is `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus 5.1.3`
I expect it will receive the message after 30 seconds but it doesn't work, could someone have a look?

Comment: What does this mean ```but it doesn't work```?

Comment: It processes the message right away without any delay @MarkusMeyer

Comment: Based on your code: You are receiving a message and then you prefer that the already received message had to be sent 30 secs in the future. You have to set ```ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc``` when you put the message in the queue

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot adding `throw new Exception("test");`. When there is an exception when processing the message, it will automatically re-send. I would like to delay if DeliveryCount > 2

Comment: ok, but the Exception will force to leave the method. This is unreachable code: ```if (receivedMessage.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount > 2)```

Comment: Thank you, it should be in the catch-block and it is still not working

Comment: The received message cannot be changed in case of an exception. You have to create a new message: ```var newMessage = receivedMessage.Clone();newMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);``` You can use custom properties to track the 'custom' delivery count and queue the ```newMessage```

Comment: Use this code, 
`try { throw new Exception("test"); } catch(Exception ex) { Thread.Sleep(3000); }`

Comment: @RajkumarPalnati-MT sleeping 30s or more causes the receiver to hang or hold resouces. I would expect to receive many other messages

Comment: @MarkusMeyer Cloning will reset the `DeliveryCount` to 1. How can I keep it?

Comment: You have to use a property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.userproperties?view=azure-dotnet
Hopefully this is the correct sdk

Comment: @Monte Cristo, have you tried like this on [ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc](https://medium.com/event-driven-utopia/azure-service-bus-essentials-scheduled-messages-98fd542f9d55#:~:text=Azure%20Service%20Bus%20allows%20you%20to%20set%20an,messages%20can%20be%20canceled%20before%20the%20enqueue%20time.).

`DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30)`

Comment: Yes, I tried. I think it is the same `receivedMessage.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);`

Comment: It works with that workaround. Thanks Markus Meyer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UserProperties` as a way to workaround. Finally, it works. Thanks, @Markus Meyer

```cs
var deliveryCountKey = "DeliveryCount";
                    var deliveryCount = receivedMessage.UserProperties.ContainsKey(deliveryCountKey) ? (int)receivedMessage.UserProperties[deliveryCountKey] : 0;
                    deliveryCount = Math.Max(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.DeliveryCount, deliveryCount);

                    if (deliveryCount > 5)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Client.DeadLetterAsync(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) when (e is OperationCanceledException || e is MessageLockLostException)
                        {
                            logger.Error(e.ToString(), exception: e);
                        }
                    }
                    else if (deliveryCount > 2)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var message = receivedMessage.Clone();
                            if (message.UserProperties.ContainsKey(deliveryCountKey))
                                message.UserProperties[deliveryCountKey] = ++deliveryCount;
                            else
                                message.UserProperties.Add(deliveryCountKey, ++deliveryCount);

                            await Client.CompleteAsync(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

                            message.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                            await Client.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                        {
                            logger.Error(e.ToString(), exception: e);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            await Client.AbandonAsync(receivedMessage.SystemProperties.LockToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                        }
                        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                        {
                            logger.Error(e.ToString(), exception: e);
                        }
                    }
```